# Label in tableview header doesn't appear on ipad but on iphone

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

in my universal app I have an UITableViewController embedded in a UINavigationController. When I add a UIView to the top of the tableView and insert a UILabel which is centered in the container, the label is only visible on iPhone but not on iPad.

I tried creating a new testapp, only consisting of these two controllers, the view and the label. It works on both, iPhone and iPad. So I added two new controllers to my app in the same way and made the navigation controller the initial view controller. Label is visible on iPhone but not on iPad.

For me it seems, that I have changed some global settings in the app; on another view I have similar problems with stackViews, but I first concentrate on this "simple" problem...

Any ideas what might be wrong in my app-settings?

[tableViewController embedded in navigationController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agrie.png)

Comment: How you are setting view frame, send code snippet you have used.

Comment: I just put it together in the storyboard. Dragged uiView into the tableViewController, dragged Label into View and used autolayout.

Comment: Take a UIViewController embedded in a UINavigationController. Add View, Label, and TableView and check it

Comment: This works for me. After discarding all changes and adding a new label to my UITableViewcontroller-UIView, it works. I don't know why. 
Thank you for your help @Brjv !

Comment: Please Accept my Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a UIViewController embedded in a UINavigationController. Add View, Label, and TableView and check it

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Now I know what was the problem. Never have checked, what's going on with those size classes.

During development I changed from any/any to a smaller size, not knowing, that this is not only taking effect on the layout in the storyboard. Everything I added after changing did'nt show on iPad.

Solution: Select storyboard, in "File Inspector", uncheck "Use Size Classes"